# Font Awesome icon inside controlgroup textbox

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, font-awesome

Below is my code:

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn">
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn">
 </fieldset>
```

my question is i want to add font awesome icons like fa-user and fa-lock inside the input text fields like below graphic, not as placeholder text! these two inputs should be in controlgroup.

below is the url for sample output
http://www.gfi.com/~/media/Images/GFI/Products/Downloads/Mobile%20app/Android/login.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/389/

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
    <label> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" />
    </label>
    <label><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>

        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" />
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#0079C1
}
fieldset {
    margin:0 auto;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
label {
    display:block;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
}
label:first-child {
    border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
label:last-child {
    border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
}
label i, label input {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:none;
    background:inherit;
    color:#BFBFBF
}
label i {
    width:20px;
    font-size:20px
}
label input {
    padding:5px;
    width:200px
}
```

You'll need to modify the html a bit. Since you need fontawesome icons, you'll have to use extra tags. This could have done by using background-image, but for that you can not use fontawesome.